# How to include CSS rules of a CSS file into some selector of anther CSS file?

Tags: css

I have a css file called main.css and another one called style.css.
how can I do this in main.css ?

```
.someClass {
 //apply rules to this class from style.css
}
```

Comment: write same selector in style.css

Comment: First must import css file into that file then you can use any of that file selector.

Comment: If you can change your stack, it would be an easy thing to do in Sass: https://sass-lang.com/guide

Answer (score -1):

You can import css file into that file.

```
@import url("main.css");
```